# global Keywoard in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, global-variables

I want to use variables from a function outside the function in python. I'm trying this:

```
def hello():
    global a
    a = 15

print(a)
```

But it's not working. How can I solve this?

Comment: You could return your value by your function.

Comment: Frankly speaking, `global` is mostly used by newcomers who have not understood function arguments and return values, yet.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call declare the global, then call the function if you want a = 15

```
a = 0 # not needed but it still works
def hello():
    global a
    a = 15

hello()
print(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you would have to call your function to actually assign the variable "a" a value.

```
def hello():
  global a
  a = 15
hello()
print(a)
```

Without calling the function, nothing written inside of it actually happens, and therefore the variable "a" does not exist yet.

Comment: Thank you very much, you wouldn't believe how much time I spent to solve this issue!

Comment: But please be aware that experienced programmers try to avoid `global` because the resulting code is high on maintenance and low on flexibility.